# Finding transformation that transforms circle into ellipse

Tags: coordinates, geometry, ellipse, affinetransform

I'm looking for a way to determine a specific transformation:

[image]

There is a circle as an equation like

x^2 + y^2 = z

and an ellipse as

x'^2 + px'y' + qy'^2 + r = 0.

(Notice that both the circle's and the ellipse's center is at 0|0 )

Given the values of z, p, q and r, how can you determine the parameters of the transformation matrix a, b, c and d for a transformation that transforms the circle into the ellipse?

And is it possible to transform the circle into any ellipse that way?

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible to transform a circle into an ellipse. For example, using a non-uniform scaling with scaleX=2.0 and scaleY=1.0, you will get (a,b,c,d)=(2,0,0,1) and the ellipse equation will be (x'/2)^2+y'^2=z. However, the transformation matrix between a circle and an ellipse is not unique. For example, using a non-uniform scaling with scaleX=1.0 and scaleY=2.0, followed by a -90 degree rotation, you will get (a,b,c,d)=(0, 2, -1, 0) and the ellipse equation is still (x'/2)^2+y'^2=z.